# How to align elements from different stacks/containers in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I would like to build a screen with SwiftUI which consists out of three HStacks. Each of these HStacks has a VStack with a button and some text under the button.
How can I make sure that the buttons are all aligned in the center regardless how long the text may be?

Comment: Please add some code and design for what you want.

Comment: The three H Stacks need to be contained in some other view (eg a VStack), but apart from that, as far as I can see, the layout that you're asking for is default SwiftUI behaviour for a VStack in an HStack.